# Parsing JSON Using Newtonsoft.Json Without Knowing the Structure

Tags: c#, json, json.net, swagger

I'm working on a project that involves automating API calls using a Swagger Definition. I download the swagger.json file. The structure of the JSON Object I need to parse is not consistent. When parsing paths, there are a list of objects, then within that they have the methods that can be used for that specific path. I can retrieve just the path using various string methods but my question was, is there a good way to parse json if the JSON is structured in such a way that it does not have a firm key? Here is an example of what I mean:

```
{"/user": {
    "post": {
      "tags": [
        "user"
      ],
      "summary": "Create user",
      "description": "This can only be done by the logged in user.",
      "operationId": "createUser",
      "consumes": [
        "application/json"
      ],
      "produces": [
        "application/json",
        "application/xml"
      ],
      "parameters": [
        {
          "in": "body",
          "name": "body",
          "description": "Created user object",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
          }
        }
      ],
      "responses": {
        "default": {
          "description": "successful operation"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If I wanted to just parse that path and retrieve the method object how could I go about that considering sometimes the object will be "post" or sometimes it will be "get", "put", etc depending on what is allowable for the path.

```
            JObject jsonResp = swaggerDownload();
            JObject paths = (JObject)jsonResp["paths"];
            foreach (var i in paths)
            {
                string pathToString = i.ToString();
                var shaveSomethings = pathToString.Substring(1, something.Length - 2);
                var pathAndJson = shaveSomethings.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2);
                string correctJsonStructure = "{\"" + pathAndJson[0] + "\":" + pathAndJson[1] + "}";
                JObject bd = JObject.Parse(correctJsonStructure);
                //dynamic pathsTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(correctJsonStructure);
                //JObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(correctJsonStructure);
                //Console.WriteLine(bd["/user"]);

            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The swagger.json file should have full definition of each entity that endpoints return. You can follow [How to create Rest API client](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-rest-api-service-client-using-swagger-and-rest-api-client-tool/) to get a working client.

I've dealt with an API where responses didn't always match the definition. I saved all responses to a store/log first and then would try to de-serialize JSON. In case of an exception I would go back to store/log and see what was different and update my code to accommodate for the change. After few iterations there were no new changes and the ordeal was over.

Hope that helps.